# html traffic light still failing, using dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I hate to ask again but i am still habeing problems wit my code fo4r my traffic lights i have amended some of it but there are still some issues for example the button does not appear, i am programming in dreamweaver and the code is html.

```
<p>This is my Traffic Light script</p>

<img id="image" src="RedLight.jpg";

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>

</head>

<body>
<script>
var list=["RedLight.jpg","RedAmberLight.jpg","GreenLight.jpg","AmberLight.jpg"]

var lighton = "Red"

function changeLights() {

    if (lighton=="Red") {
        image.src=list[1];
    lighton="RedAmber";}


    if (lighton=="RedAmber") {
        image.src=list[2];
    lighton="Green";}


    if (lighton=="Green") {
        image.src=list[3];
    lighton="Amber";}


    else{
        image.src=list[3];
    lighton="Red";}

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: fix this line: `<img id="image" src="RedLight.jpg";` . It should look: `<img id="image" src="RedLight.jpg">`

Comment: and move your code from `<head>` to `<body>`

Comment: still no images appear so still not working dont know what the problem is the button comes up and so does a box with a cross in it

Comment: check paths to images

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
<body>

<p>This is my Traffic Light script</p>

<img id="image" src="RedLight.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>

<script>
var list=["RedLight.jpg","RedAmberLight.jpg","GreenLight.jpg","AmberLight.jpg"]
var lighton = "Red"
function changeLights() {
    if (lighton=="Red") {
         document.getElementById("image").src = list[1];
        lighton="RedAmber";
    }
        else if (lighton=="RedAmber") {
            document.getElementById("image").src=list[2];
            lighton="Green";
        }
            else if (lighton=="Green") {
                document.getElementById("image").src=list[3];
                lighton="Amber";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("image").src=list[0];
                lighton="Red";
            }
}
</script>
</body>
```